# C# Invoke a delegate that operates on UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm having trouble with threads and UI code. I want a deeply nested subclass to invoke a ui change, write to a textbox. This from a new thread. The background is I have a server class and error notifications can fire from different clients on different threads. I want all notifications to end up in the same textbox. I have simplified the code alot to aid debugging, but I have verified that it reproduces the error. Only "hello2" displays in the text box but I want "hello1" also.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ehcontainer ehc;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ehc = new ehcontainer();
        ehc.eh.em.Notifier = WriteToTextBox;
    }

    // Attempting to only run from UI thread
    private void WriteToTextBox(string message)
    {
        if (!log_TextBox.CheckAccess())
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => apptext(message));
            return;
        }

        apptext(message);
    }

    private void apptext(string message)
    {
        log_TextBox.AppendText(message + "\n");
    }

    // Only hello2 is written to text box
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ehc.NewWriteThread("hello1");
        ehc.Write("hello2");
    }
}

public class ehcontainer
{
    public errorhandler eh = new errorhandler();

    public void NewWriteThread(string message)
    {
        ehcontainer tempEHC = new ehcontainer();
        Thread newThread = new Thread(tempEHC.Write);
        newThread.Start(message);
    }

    public void Write(object obj)
    {
        string sMessage = (string)obj;

        eh.em.Notify(sMessage);
    }
}

public class errorhandler
{
    public errormessenger em;

    public errorhandler()
    {
        em = new errormessenger();
    }
}

public class errormessenger
{
    public delegate void NotifyMethod(string message);
    private NotifyMethod myNotifyMethod = null;

    public NotifyMethod Notifier
    {
        get { return myNotifyMethod; }
        set { myNotifyMethod = value; }
    }

    // Run a delegate that calls some notification function in UI thread
    public void Notify(string message)
    {
        myNotifyMethod?.Invoke(message);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am running AppendText on the textbox.

Comment: I would think about Messaging as this concepts decouples components very nicely. Have a look at MvvM Light Toolkit Messenger.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `TextWrapping="Wrap"` and `AcceptsReturn="True"` on the log_TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Your `errormessenger` has no `Notifier`. Why? The key is that you're creating a new `ehcontainer` when calling `ehcontainer.NewWriteThread` - and you never assign the `Notifier` from the old container to the new one.

How to fix this depends entirely on your logic. I have no idea what you're trying to do, and why you chose this solution in particular to do it. Why are you using C# 6 features, and yet choose to use `Thread` instead of `Task`, for example?